# Youtube video on AIR iOS app isn't displayed anymore with AIR 23

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, youtube, air, stagewebview

I'm updating my iOS AIR app, and when I compile my IPA file using AIR 23, Youtube videos refuse to show up within my app.

When I compile with AIR 20, everything goes back to normal, and youtube videos run normally on an iPhone.

I'm using the "StageWebView + iframe" method to display the video within the AIR app.

The code I use is written below, is there anything I need to change to make it compatible with AIR V23?    Thanks a lot!!!!

> ```
>            webViewYoutube = new StageWebView();
>
>            webViewYoutube.stage=stage;
>
>
>
>            var htmlString:String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" +
>
>                     "<html><body bgcolor="+ "Black" + "><script>" +
>
>                     "var tag = document.createElement('script');"+
>
>                     "tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\";"+
>
>                     "var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];"+
>
>                     "firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);"+
>
>                     "var player;"+           
>
>                     "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {"+
>
>                         "player = new YT.Player('player', {"+            
>
>                           "events: {"+
>
>                             "'onReady': onPlayerReady,"+
>
>                           "}"+
>
>                         "});"+
>
>                     "}"+
>
>                     "function onPlayerReady(event) {"+
>
>                         "event.target.playVideo();"+
>
>                     "}"+
>
>                     "</script>"+
>
>                     "<iframe id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXXX?autohide=1&controls=1&modestbranding=0&rel=0&showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>" +
>
>                     "</body></html>";
>
>
>
>            webViewYoutube.loadString(htmlString);
>
>            swvHeight = stage.stageHeight;
>
>            webViewYoutube.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.stage.stageWidth, swvHeight);
> ```

Comment: Try using `https://` instead of usual `http://` in your code. That might help you...

Comment: PS: Didn't notice you were using `player_api` within a stagewebView. For showing inside a web viewport try this [**tutorial**](http://www.monday8am.com/en/2013/01/20/youtube-air-and-stagewebview/) instead (ie: just load an **embed** player not an **API player**).

Comment: Hi  VC.One, you’re such a life saver! The HTTPS solution worked like a charm!
I’ll definitely look at the tutorial you pointed at when I’ll have some time.
Thanks again!

Comment: @NealDavis When I hover over the correct answer, I see no check mark.. Are you sure I can mark a comment as the right answer? Thank you!